# Плавное увеличение части картинки на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, анимация

Есть картинка, на которой есть несколько объектов. При клике на объект должно происходить плавное увеличение, как эффект наезжания камеры, до того момента пока объект не будет на весь экран. Я сделал вариант с разделением картинки на несколько более мелких, соединением их и при клике увеличивать на весь экран блок с объектом, но пока это слабо походит на "наезжание камеры".
Вопросы:
Как сделать плавный сдвиг всех остальных блоков (или уменьшение этих блоков) при клике на один из блоков (в моем примере блоки заменяют кусочки картинки), чтобы создался эффект наезда камеры?

```js
console.clear();

var root  = document.documentElement;
var body  = document.body;
var pages = document.querySelectorAll(".page");
var tiles = document.querySelectorAll(".tile");

for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {  
  addListeners(tiles[i], pages[i]);
}

function addListeners(tile, page) {
  
  tile.addEventListener("click", function() {
    animateHero(tile, page);
  });
  
  page.addEventListener("click", function() {
    animateHero(page, tile);
  });  
}

function animateHero(fromHero, toHero) {
    
  var clone = fromHero.cloneNode(true);
      
  var from = calculatePosition(fromHero);
  var to = calculatePosition(toHero);
  
  TweenLite.set([fromHero, toHero], { visibility: "hidden" });
  TweenLite.set(clone, { position: "absolute", margin: 0 });
  
  body.appendChild(clone);  
      
  var style = {
    x: to.left - from.left,
    y: to.top - from.top,
    width: to.width,
    height: to.height,
    autoRound: false,
    ease: Power1.easeOut,
    onComplete: onComplete
  };
   
  TweenLite.set(clone, from);  
  TweenLite.to(clone, 2, style)
    
  function onComplete() {
    
    TweenLite.set(toHero, { visibility: "visible" });
    body.removeChild(clone);
  }
}

function calculatePosition(element) {
    
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  var scrollTop  = window.pageYOffset || root.scrollTop  || body.scrollTop  || 0;
  var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || root.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft || 0;
  
  var clientTop  = root.clientTop  || body.clientTop  || 0;
  var clientLeft = root.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;
    
  return {
    top: Math.round(rect.top + scrollTop - clientTop),
    left: Math.round(rect.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft),
    height: rect.height,
    width: rect.width,
  };
}
```

```css
  
  .tile {
    width: 49vw;
    height: 50vh;
    cursor: pointer;  
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .page-container {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .page {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
  }
  
  .hero-1 {
    background: red;
  }
  
  .hero-2 {
    background: #000;
  }
  
  .hero-3 {
    background: #7DD6FE;
  }
  
  .hero-4 {
    background: #DC3C84;
  }
```

```html
          <div class="tile hero-1"></div>
          <div class="tile hero-2"></div>
          <div class="tile hero-3"></div>
          <div class="tile hero-4"></div>
      
      <div class="page-container">
        <div class="page hero-1"></div>
        <div class="page hero-2"></div>
        <div class="page hero-3"></div>
        <div class="page hero-4"></div>
      </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Объясните русским языком, что вы понимаете под словом `наезд`?

Comment: @did В моем примере - при клике на блок - прямо пропорциональное уменьшение трех остальных, относительно увеличения первого

Comment: А в какую сторону их направлять? в один угол или в разные углы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так чтоли?

```js
  
    blMain.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(function($section) {

      $section.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!$section.getAttribute('data-open')) {
          $section.setAttribute('data-open', true);
          $section.classList.add('bl-expand');
          $section.classList.add('bl-expand-top');
          blMain.classList.add('bl-expand-item');
        }
      })
      
      $section.querySelector('span.bl-icon-close').addEventListener('click',(event)=> {
        event.stopPropagation();
        let $section = event.target.closest('section');
        $section.removeAttribute('data-open');
        $section.classList.remove('bl-expand');
        $section.addEventListener('transitionend', function onTransitionEnd(event) {
          if (!event.target.matches('section')){
            return event.stopPropagation();
          }
          $section.removeEventListener('transitionend',onTransitionEnd);
          $section.classList.remove('bl-expand-top');
        });
        blMain.classList.remove('bl-expand-item');
      });
    });
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #f2ede3;
  background: #333;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a {
  color: #f0f0f0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.bl-main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bl-main>section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.bl-main>section:first-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #F06060;
}

.bl-main>section:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: #FA987D;
}

.bl-main>section:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: #72CCA7;
}

.bl-main>section:nth-child(4) {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #10A296;
}

.bl-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bl-box h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.bl-icon {
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.bl-icon:before {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bl-icon-about:before {
  content: "⌬";
}

.bl-icon-works:before {
  content: "⎈";
}

.bl-icon-blog:before {
  content: "〠";
}

.bl-icon-contact:before {
  content: "⚠";
}

.bl-main>section .bl-icon-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.bl-icon-close:before {
  content: "⊗";
}

.bl-content,
div.bl-panel-items>div>div {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.bl-main>section {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.bl-main>section.bl-expand {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.bl-main>section.bl-expand-top {
  z-index: 100;
}

.bl-main>section:first-child.bl-expand {
  background: #EE4444;
}

.bl-main>section:nth-child(2).bl-expand {
  background: #F98262;
}

.bl-main>section:nth-child(3).bl-expand {
  background: #4BBE8E;
}

.bl-main>section:nth-child(4).bl-expand {
  background: #0D8278;
}

.bl-main.bl-expand-item>section:not(.bl-expand),
.bl-main.bl-expand-item>section.bl-scale-down {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
}

.bl-box {
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear 0.5s;
}

section.bl-expand .bl-box {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s linear;
}

.bl-box h2 {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.no-touch section:not(.bl-expand) .bl-box:hover h2 {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.bl-content,
.bl-icon-close {
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear 0s;
}

section.bl-expand .bl-content,
section.bl-expand .bl-icon-close {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear 0.5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 46.5em) {
  .bl-content,
  .bl-box {
    font-size: 75%;
  }
  .bl-expand .bl-box {
    height: 130px;
  }
  .bl-content>ul li {
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="blMain" class="bl-main">
    <section>
      <div class="bl-box">
        <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-about">About</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="bl-content">
      </div>
      <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
    </section>
    <section id="bl-work-section">
      <div class="bl-box">
        <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-works">Works</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="bl-content">
      </div>
      <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="bl-box">
        <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-blog">Blog</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="bl-content">
      </div>
      <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="bl-box">
        <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-contact">Contact</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="bl-content">
      </div>
      <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://github.com/codrops/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions)

Comment: Измените ссылку на источник, которая удовлетворяет требованиям лицензии  [Наименование статьи](ссылка на статью) [от  автора](ссылка на профиль). У вас же ссылка на полный экран без автора, это нарушение лицензии

Comment: Приношу извинения, и сам не понял как так скопировал не ту ссылку, думал на github ведет, это оказался сайт третьих лиц.

Comment: и у меня ещё одна просьба к Вам. На enSO топики без кода попытки решения тут же заминусовываются и закрываются.Минусуют и ответы тоже, так как это [обязательное требование по оформлению вопросов и у них и у нас](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) чтобы неповадно было отвечать на такие вопросы. Видимо и нам стоит, кончать баловать халявщиков. Это относится к другим Вашим ответам по вопросам без кода попытки. Здесь вопрос отвечает требованиям на 100%

Comment: @Alexandr_TT не дезинформируйте людей, на enSO *хорошие* топики без кода (а код по правилам [вовсе не требуется](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8bYs.png)) вполне себе плюсуются. Примеры: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598575), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787167), [три](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889836) (третий пример меня вообще бесконечно повеселил)