# Попеременно выводить елементы DOM на экран

Tags: javascript, dom, position

Есть следующий код

```
<h1 onclick="showCard(event)">img1</h1>
<h1 onclick="showCard(event)">img2</h1>
<div class="images" id="img1"><img/></div>
<div class="images" id="img2"><img/></div>


.images {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 100%;
}


let imgs = {
   'img1': document.querySelector('#img1'),
   'img2': document.querySelector('#img2')
}

function showCard(e) {
    if (imgs[e.target.innerText.toLowerCase()].id === e.target.innerText.toLowerCase()) {
        imgs[e.target.innerText.toLowerCase()].style.left = '50%'
    } else {
        imgs[e.target.innerText.toLowerCase()].style.left = '100%'
    }
}
```

Задача стоит в следующем: не могу корректно написать логику, чтобы при нажатии на img1 с экрана уходила img2 и наоборот. Сейчас код работает следующим образом: при нажатии на img1 выходит первая картинка, при нажатии на img2 выходит вторая картинка, но первая остается под ней, а необходимо сделать так, чтобы при выходе второй картинки первая уходила за границы экрана.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подправить код. Или может есть инные варианты исполнения. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `<div>` подставте в код свои картинки.

```js
let red = document.querySelector('div.red'),
    green = document.querySelector('div.green'),
    onclick = () => { 
      red.classList.toggle('show');
      green.classList.toggle('show');
    };
    
red.addEventListener('click', onclick, false);
green.addEventListener('click', onclick, false);
```

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
.red {left:-100%;background:red;}
.green {left: 100%;background:green;}
.red,.green{position:absolute;width:100vw;height:100vh;transition:left .2s;}
.show{left:0;display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="red show"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Единственное, я жму добавить картинку и соответственно, если я нажму на нее еще раз, она пропадает. Но как сделать, чтобы я нажал на вторую картинку, и первая пропала? Я беру ситуацию, если у меня не 2 картинки, а 30 скажем. Чтобы я нажал на любую картинку, она открылась, а все остальные с экрана пропали. Имеется ввиду чтобы выводилась только определенная картинка?

Comment: Ааа, так, я вас понял, у вас сначала отображаются все картинки и вы хотите чтобы после клика на картинку отображалась она одна? Посмотрите на всякий случай ещё мой ответ здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209659/406363

Comment: @faceVB а так, то что вы хотите, называется среди профессионалов верстальщиков понятие `lightbox`. Есть хороший сайт, жаль на английском языке, но там и так вроде все понятно: https://www.cssscript.com/tag/gallery-lightbox/ .  Полистайте этот сайт, посмотрите разные решения. Там напротив каждой библиотеки есть кнопка `Demo`, которая показывает скрипт в действии., а если нажать на заголовок статьи, то откроется инструкция по внедрению скрипта на свой сайт.

Comment: Почитаю, спасибо. Получилось сделать, манипулируя классом show.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сделать это более универсально, для этого:

1. отображаемому img добавьте класс индикатор (пример: `class="show"`)
2. в функцию `showCard(nextImgId)` передавайте id картинки для отображения
3. в функцие `showCard(nextImgId)`, находите элемент с классом "show" и удаляете его, находите элемент с id=nextImgId и ему добавляете класс "show"
4. в css для img добавить стиль `left=100%` а для img.show `left=50%`

так же анимации можно добавить плавности с помощью [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Comment: Не совсем понял как это реализовать. Напишите код, пожалуйста, для примера. Я беру ситуацию, если у меня не 2 картинки, а 30 скажем. Чтобы я нажал на любую картинку, она открылась, а все остальные с экрана пропали. Имеется ввиду чтобы выводилась только определенная картинка?